# Cron zero'th of month

Tags: cron

What would the zero'th of a month mean in the following scheduler?
never or every day?

```
 shops.import.cron.expression=0 5 0 * * ?
```

i see that it is at 5:00 am but I can't find any definition of what the 0th of a month means.

Comment: Depends on the particular implementation of cron you're using.

Comment: hmm, ok. I am not sure which one but it's part of the spring framework  v3.1. maybe quartz from opensymphony?